# Can I stylize the trademark symbol to match logo design?

Tags: logo, symbols, trademark

I need to know if the trademark (™) symbol has to remain fairly generic in styling, or can it by made to match the style of a logo?

Comment: I wouldn't as people may think the "tm" is part of the logos name

Comment: If you stylize your &trade; you might have to trademark your &trade; ; then you would want to stylize *that* &trade;... &trade;ception!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**I am not a trademark attorney** which is really who you should ask.

My understanding is the ™ is merely an indicator that the mark is being used in an effort to register it. ™ means *"We intend to make this an ® when unique usage has been established."* ™ does not provide any legal protection, it merely is a notice to infringers that the user may *intend* to file a registration claim. The more you "design" the ™ the more you convolute that warning.

™ is *never* meant to be *part* of a logotype. You really don't design around the ™. It may change to a ® when the mark is registered. You should design your logotype without considering the ™. Then place the ™ in the most optimum location for visibility.

All this taken into account -- Yes, you *can* style the ™ to some degree. However, be careful not to alter it so much that it no longer appears to be the actual ™ mark. And be aware that it may be removed or replaced at some point so your logo should *never* rely on the ™ being present.

Comment: Thanks for that, Scott! Not a whole bunch of info that relates directly to this on the web. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am also not a trademark attorney, however I think you can style the TM how you please. I wanted to share this relevant video about Levi's and their approach to handling the trademark: http://www.fastcodesign.com/3036283/how-levis-turned-a-design-evil-into-a-design-signature